# Display uitextfield above keyboard using IQKeyboardReturnKeyHandler

Tags: ios, iphone, uitextfield, iqkeyboardmanager

Im using an `IQKeyboardReturnKeyHandler` to display my keyboard, my question: is it possible to display a `UITextField` in the `UIToolbar` of `IQKeyboardManager` - if so, can you teach me how to display it in code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cannot display your textfield into the toolBar of IQ keyboard manager.